# Php SoapClient timeout (ubuntu)

Tags: php, ubuntu, soap, apache2

Am trying to call a soap on the network but i keep getting a timeout(am using Linux Mint), i can tell its a timeout because it takes a while before it comes back with an error... i tried both nusoap and soapclient... the nusoap is throwing "HTTP Error: Unsupported HTTP response status 303 See Other (soapclient->response has contents of the response)"...
I tested the code on windows os and its working...
Below is the code tho:

```
        $client=new SoapClient('http://192.168.1.77:8080/project/Login?wsdl');


        $result = $client->__soapCall("checkUserCred", array(
        "checkUserCred" => array(
            "user"        => 'admin',
            "password"    => "admin"        // The ads ID
        )
    ), NULL, NULL);

    echo $result->return;
```

Is there anyway to debug this, am sure its from ubuntu(linx mint) but can't tell what exactly... I tried looking at the apache2 logs file but couldn't find anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems fine, it looks like it's more or less a connection issue.  On terminal try to telnet to your server and see what you get...

Something like: 
telnet 192.168.1.77 8080

If telnet does respond and allows you to enter something then try to do:
GET /project/Login?wsdl

And hit enter twice.  See if you get the WSDL returned properly.  You will also need to take a look at your WSDL to see where the endpoint is and do something similar to the endpoint URL to make sure you have connectivity

Alternatively you can do a TCP traceroute as root user to see where it's routing to with

```
traceroute -T -p 8080 192.168.1.77
```

Note here: to do a TCP traceroute you have to be root user / sudo command.